# Spring bean loading and test setup method order

Tags: java, spring, spock

Let's suppose there's a test like this:

```
@ActiveProfiles(value = "test")
@SpringBootTest(classes = AbcApplication.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class AbcTest extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    Foo foo

    @Autowired
    Bar bar

    void setup() {
        foo.setBar(bar)
    }

    def 'some test case'() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I need to execute `foo.setBar(bar)` as early in the Spring application context's startup as possible. `Foo` and `Bar` are beans created through autoconfiguration, thus I can not instantiate them manually before Spring Boot startup is launched (i.e. using `static` block).

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: You definitely want to inject one bean into another after beans were properly created by Spring. Right?
In that case I'd use injection on ContextRefreshedEvent or try to inject beans in BeanPostProcessors (second phase, after they were wrapped in necessary proxies).

Comment: Why isn't `bar` injected into `foo` by Spring, isn't that the purpose of a di-framework?

Comment: @LeonardBrünings technically, they can be. But in general, connecting `foo` and `bar` is not a good practice as they are separate entities, responsible for very different functionalities, that do not neccessarily go together.

Comment: @AlexeyGorelik not really. I want the `foo.setBar(bar)` be executed (with `foo` and `bar` already autowired, obviously) as early in the Spring context as possible, not once it was launched.

Comment: If connecting `foo` and `bar` is bad practice, why do you do it then? You do connect them, you just do it manually instead of letting DI do it.